# PHP namespace aliasing works strangely

Tags: php, namespaces

I came across an issue with regards to PHP namespace this morning, a friend of mine asked me if I knew what's wrong but I wasn't sure. I can't remember the whole code piece but basically this short snippet is what makes me confused:

```
try {
   echo "A";
   $bootstrap = new \Test\Built\Framework\Bootstrap;
   echo "B";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    throw $e;
}
```

When the script executed, I could see "A" being printed out, but not "B", given that there was no error found (no exception being thrown too).

Since I'm not really familiar with PHP namespace, I just have 2 questions:

1. What's wrong with the code as not printing either "B" or error?
2. What does `$bootstrap = new \Test\Built\Framework\Bootstrap;` actually do? How is it being loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably class 'Test\Built\Framework\Bootstrap' is not found and the php **display_errors** is set to **Off**.

That's why the error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test\Built\Framework\Bootstrap' not found in ...
```

it's not printed in the sceen. The script echos A and the exits with fatal error.

The code

`$bootstrap = new \Test\Built\Framework\Bootstrap;`

creates a new object from the class

```
<?php namespace Test\Built\Framework;

class Bootstrap {}

?>
```

To use the Bootstrap class in your script you have to include it specifically or use an autoloader.